# How to send a form delete request with Node/Express and AJAX?

Tags: node.js, ajax, express

I'm trying to build a REST API with NodeJs and Express (I'm a very beginner in programming), the CRUD requests work fine in Postman, but now I don't know how to send a DELETE request through a form with AJAX. I just want insert an id the text input and submit it to the server to delete a document in MongoDB. I searched everywhere but I could not understand how to perform this.

**App.js**

```js
app.delete('/delete/:id', (req, res) => {
  let id = req.params.id;
  if (!ObjectID.isValid(id)) {
    return res.status(400).send();
  }
  Blog.findByIdAndRemove(id).then((docs) => {
    res.status(200).send({docs})
  }).catch((e) => {
    res.status(400)
  });
});
```

**HTML**

```html
                                                   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Titolo</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action='/delete/:id' method="POST">
      <input id="id" type="text" name="id" /><br />
      <button id:"cancella" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>

    <script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**script.js**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#cancella').on("click", function() {
  var id = $('#id').val();
  $.ajax({
   url: '/delete/:id',
   type: 'DELETE',
   data: {"id": id},
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function(data) {
    //do something
  }});
 });
});
```

Comment: Your form has a POST method and I'm not sure HTML form supports DELETE method anyway.

Answer (score 6):

HTML forms don't support PUT or DELETE methods but Node apps there are workarounds like this https://github.com/expressjs/method-override

Answer (score 4):

Your form should have a hidden field that shows you are making a delete request like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Titolo</title>
</head>
  <body>
<form action='/delete/:id' method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT"/>
  <input id="id" type="text" name="id" /><br />
  <button id:"cancella" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Using `/delete` should no longer be necessary if you are sending a delete request since it is redundant.

Answer (score 2):

If You want to send DELETE request by submitting the form through Ajax to App.js file, First Build Html form, build ajax script and at the last build a route at app.js file that listen to your Delete Request.Do Like This ..

In **HTML**

```html
<form class="delete-form">
    <input id="id" type="text" name="id" /><br />
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

In **Script.js**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('.delete-form').on("click", function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          var id = $('#id').val();
          $.ajax({
              type: 'DELETE',
              url: '/delete/' + id,
              success: (data) => {
                console.log(data);
              },
              error: (err) => {
                console.log(error);
              });
          });
      });
```

**App.js**

```js
app.delete('/delete/:id', (req, res) => {
  let id = req.params.id;
  if (!ObjectID.isValid(id)) {
    return res.status(400).send();
  }
  Blog.findByIdAndRemove(id).then((docs) => {
    res.status(200).send({
      docs
    })
  }).catch((e) => {
    res.status(400)
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
**action='/delete/:thisIsDynamicId'**
```

> You can also use this in html. It works correctly, the action of the
> form has to pass a dynamic id.

```
<html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Titolo</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <form action='/delete/:thisIsDynamicId' method="POST">
          <button id:"cancella" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    
        <script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/script.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```