# Express - NodeJs method-override Can not DELETE

Tags: node.js, express, x-http-method-override

I try using method overwrite on Express Js to overwrite method POST on form to Delete method.
Here is my config

On the view, I add form for submission with following code

```
<form method="Post" id="delete-product-form"></form>
// Action for form submission
<script>
  const delBtn = document.querySelector('#btn-delete-confirm');
  delBtn.onclick = function() {
    delForm.action = `/admin/item-list/${delId}?_method=delete`;
    delForm.submit();
  }
</script>
```

And this is my config on router

```
router.delete('/admin/item-list/:id', (req,res,next) => {
   productsModel.deleteOne({_id: req.params.id})
        .then(() => res.redirect('back'))
        .catch(next);
  }
});
```

I test and recieve the following message on browser (directly on browser not on dev tool)

**Cannot DELETE /admin/item-list/653fcd8a48b2e3a79b0affc0**

If I change method to GET on form method and Router, it works normally. It is really weird that i can not overwrite the POST to delete.

Which step am I wrong? Please help me out.
Thanks you so much

Find the reason that my codes do not work properly

Comment: Have you tried using `<form method="delete" ...`? Have you installed the [method-override middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/method-override.html) in express?

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45522579/how-to-send-a-form-delete-request-with-node-express-and-ajax) question will help.